# Is it possible to execute a long running function before the browser is reloaded?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, indexeddb, user-experience

I do prevent a page reload in my web application by the following function:

```
window.onbeforeunload = (event) => {
  const e = event || window.event;
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();

  save_user_data_to_indexed_db();

  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = ''; // Legacy method for cross browser support
  }
  return ''; // Legacy method for cross browser support
};
```

However, the `save_user_data_to_indexed_db()` function is not being executed during the "Reload site?" message. I thought that if I could execute my function during the displayed message, I could maybe automatically answer the same dialog programmatically and let the browser continue reloading the page.

Is there a way to make the browser wait for this kind of operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, there is no way to make the browser wait. What I often do in this case is write the data to an intermediate place, such as localStorage, synchronously, and then asynchronously copy that data over to indexedDB later on when there is time, such as when the page is next loaded again, or from within a service worker.